# Tracking Location

Tags: android, location

I am working on a mobile ordering app and in that I want to give the live tracking feature to the user where the user can constantly check the status/location of  the order on his/her phone and track it till it arrives at the user doorstep.

I know we can get  the location of phone in android using Gcm provider or network provider.The point I am stuck at is,the user will be tapping on button "track order" and the location needs to be tracked of the delivery boy on the way.So,how can i achieve that,as something in between of the user and the delivery boy is needed.When the user taps the button something is needed to get the current location of the delivery boy and  get the user updated about that.Many ordering apps have already achieved that.Please help me out ,atleast with the rough idea.I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You need some server in between to accept the gps coordinates of delivery boy so the user who ordered can fetch those coordinates and see them.

So either you create your own server or you use some servers like [Dweet.io](http://dweet.io/).

let's say you're using dweet.io, then:

1. You need to create an unique endpoint on dweet for each boy, using https://dweet.io/dweet/for/delivery-boy-name?lat=22.454&long=54.54
   where `delivery-boy-name`is your endpoint, and lat & long are the coordinates.
2. And then on user and you need to fetch the coordinates using: https://dweet.io/get/dweets/for/delivery-boy-name where `delivery-boy-name` is the unique name of boy.

And to make this happen, first you need the boy name or the boy url on the user side.

Hope it gives you idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.could you please tell me,how will server get the lat-long coordinates of delivery boy?

Comment: for every 10 mtr (or whatever location change you want) to notify user just set it in Delivery boy application using LocationManager and when you get location change just call you server API to post location of delivery boy and then push it User Application using PUSH NOTIFICATION SERVICE (GCM/ XMPP)

Comment: @VasundharaKanojia you need to upload data from the d boy end after pre-defined interval

Answer (score 0):

In a On-Demand Delivery service application, the order tracking is the necessary feature so that the user can aware of the order status and current location of product in maps. The effective user experience is showing every status of the order and updating location values in Maps.

A customized solution available is integrating a Teliver SDK in your android application. Using [Live Tracking Made Easier](https://teliver.io). The location of a delivery agent can be easily tracked by a user and the deliverer can also send custom push notification to the customer while delivering the order.

In your On-Demand Delivery driver application once the driver is out to delivery you can use the Teliver.startTrip( ) method to start a trip in driver side, and can send a push notification indicating that the order is dispatched from store and the driver is OnRoute. Here the customer now can track the driver in map. Using Teliver.startTracking( ) method in On-Demand Delivery customer application. visit [Live Tracking Made Easier](https://teliver.io)

Every location update of the user is updated and plotted in maps till he reaches the customer place and stops the trip.

[image]